# How to upload files to Amazon S3 using Android SDK without exposing secret key

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In this tutorial: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271 secret key is used during file upload.

I can't use secret key since my app users don't have amazon account and I can't share my amazon secret key to my app users.

I want to let users upload their avatars directly to S3 without passing through own proxy that has secret key.

I know that this is somehow possible for HTML 5 apps, but haven't find a documentated way for native SDK.

Comment: Use HTTPS and request your key from your web service at the launch of the app?

Comment: If you're not worried about too many uploads, you could create a new IAM user that has permission only to upload a file, and embed those credentials in the app.

Comment: Of course, if you run your own server, there are a lot of other options, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490) to generate temporary session keys for your users. Here's an example for an [anonymous TVM](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990).

Alternatively, you can use a framework like [Filepicker.io](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/android/) which takes care of the authentication details for you.